# Is there a closed form solution to this definite integral

Tags: integration

Given the integral:

> $$\int_{0}^{2}\left(\arcsin\left(1-x\right)\right)^{2}\ln\left(e^{x}\cdot\frac{3-x}{1+x}\right)dx$$

How do you evaluate this? The answer is supposed to be $\frac{\pi^2}{2} -4$, but when I let the given integral equal I and then using both desmos and wolfram alpha to evaluate $I - (\frac{\pi^2}{2} -4)$ I get a non zero difference. I figured this can only be evaluated using numerical integration methods but does an actual definite answer exist?

Comment: Yoiu can get the proper font and spacing for $\arcsin$ and $\ln$ using `\arcsin` and `\ln`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 3):

Let $t=1-x$,then
$$\int_{0}^{2}\left(\arcsin\left(1-x\right)\right)^{2}\ln\left(e^{x}\cdot\frac{3-x}{1+x}\right)dt=\int_{-1}^{1}(\arcsin t)^{2}\ln\left(e^{1-t}\cdot\frac{2+t}{2-t}\right)dt$$
$$=\int_{-1}^{1}(\arcsin t)^{2}\left(1-t+\ln\frac{2+t}{2-t}\right)dt=\int_{-1}^{1}(\arcsin t)^{2}dx=2\int_{0}^{1}(\arcsin t)^{2}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(\pi^2-8).$$
Here we use the fact that:$$(\arcsin t)^{2}$$ is even function and 
$$(\arcsin t)^{2}\left(-t+\ln\frac{2+t}{2-t}\right)$$ is odd function
and $$\int(\arcsin t)^{2}dt=2\sqrt{1-t^2}\arcsin t-2t+t(\arcsin t)^{2}+C.$$

Comment: how does $\int_{-1}^{1} (\arcsin{t})^2(1-t+\ln{\frac{2+t}{2-t}})dt = \int_{-1}^{1} (\arcsin{t})^2dt$??

Comment: $(\arcsin t)^{2}\left(-t+\ln\frac{2+t}{2-t}\right)$ is odd function, so $\int_{-1}^1(\arcsin t)^{2}\left(-t+\ln\frac{2+t}{2-t}\right)dt=0$. @Jack Zhang

Answer (score 1):

If we let $y=2-x$, then
$$\begin{align}I_1&=\int_0^2\left(\sin^{-1}(1-x)\right)^2\ln\left(\frac{3-x}{1+x}\right)dx\\
&=\int_2^0\left(\sin^{-1}(y-1)\right)^2\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{3-y}\right)(-dy)\\
&=-\int_0^2\left(\sin^{-1}(1-y)\right)^2\ln\left(\frac{3-y}{1+y}\right)dy=0\end{align}$$
Because $0$ is the only number which is its own additive inverse. On the other hand if we let $x=1+\sin\theta$,
$$\begin{align}I_2&=\int_0^2\left(\sin^{-1}(1-x)\right)^2\ln(e^x)dx\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\theta^2(1+\sin\theta)\cos\theta\,d\theta\\
&=\left[\theta^2(\sin\theta-\frac14\cos2\theta)+2\theta(\cos\theta+\frac18\sin2\theta)-2\sin\theta+\frac18\cos2\theta\right]_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\\
&=2\left(\frac{\pi^2}4-2\right)\end{align}$$
So
$$I=I_1+I_2=\frac{\pi^2}2-4$$
As in the statement of the problem.

Comment: +1 nice answer really ...